# create Infopath forms using visual studio 2010 for sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I have a requirement that i need to create an infopath 2010 form using visual studio 2010.
can any one show mw the way to create that?

Thanks,
Suresh

Comment: The question is too vague. You need to tell us what you have tried and what failed. A simple google search shows lots of tutorials like this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg621307

Comment: i have to make info-path forms to visual studio to made a build. That's why iam asking you to make this in to vs 2010

Answer (score 1):

A *requirement*? Wierd requirement... You can not create InfoPath 2010 Forms with Visual Studio. You were able to work on InfoPath 2007 Forms with Visual Studio but this possibility is gone with InfoPath 2010.

The code behind from InfoPath from forms can only be edited using the InfoPath built in Visual Studio Tools for Applications.

Comment: thanks for reply, But there is any tools available like infopath form 2007 developement.

Comment: Yes. InfoPath Designer includes the Visual Studio Tools for Applications which allow you to develop custom code solutions. Visual Studio cannot be used!